# classe de funções matemáticas (regressão) no SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, regressão

Qual a classe para se usar equações matemáticas de regressão? E como plotar o gráfico?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma solução nativa do iOS para geração de gráficos, mas existem bibliotecas de terceiros que cumprem o trabalho muito bem. Existe uma biblioteca chamada ios-charts que foi escrita em Swift. Foi atualizada há pouco tempo então creio que está sendo constantemente melhorada. Recomendo dar uma olhada:

https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

Sobre classe para executar equações matemáticas de regressão, não conheço nenhuma biblioteca que faça isso. Talvez seja necessário que você crie uma.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado @Carl Brusell , pelo o que vi o iOS-charts irá me ajudar em algumas coisas. De resto vou ter que estudar mais as equações (cálculos) pois não é a minha área, mais uma vez obrigado